# Lambda function range() get one number always

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def multipliers():
    return [lambda x: i * x for i in range(3)]

print([m(2) for m in multipliers()])
```

how to fix this lambda function?
I except:
`[0, 2, 4]` 
I got:
`[4, 4, 4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lambda` is also a function with its local scope. To tie each `lambda` to a respective `i` counter you can pass it as an argument with default value:

```
def multipliers():
    return [lambda x, i=i: i * x for i in range(3)]

print([m(2) for m in multipliers()])  # [0, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how the `lambda`s capture the *name* `i`, not its value (and the last value of the name `i` within that listcomp will be `2`).

Add one more function that will have a local name `i`:

```
def make_multiplier(x):
    return lambda y: x * y

def multipliers():
    return [make_multiplier(i) for i in range(3)]

print([m(2) for m in multipliers()])
```